# core-splitter within core-header-panel doesn't have 100% height?

Tags: polymer, flexbox

Below is the body of my HTML.

```
01 <body fullbleed layout vertical>
02 <template is="auto-binding">
03 
04    <!-- Content -->
05    <core-header-panel flex>
06        <core-toolbar>
07            <div>Hello World!</div>
08        </core-toolbar>
09        <div horizontal layout>
10            <div>left</div>
11            <core-splitter direction="left"></core-splitter>
12            <div flex>
13                <!-- I have some looped elements here-->
14            </div>
15        </div>
16    </core-header-panel>
17    <!-- /Content -->
18 </template>
19 <!--scripts loaded here-->
20 </body>
```

Here is what it looks like in the browser:

[image]

So before I go adding CSS to line 09 I thought I'd see if anyone knew the polymer (flexbox) way of fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `core-header-panel` uses a combination of absolute and relative positioned divs.
The insertion point for the main content is wrapped inside a div with `position:relative`

So the easiest solution is to add the `fit` ([docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#general-purpose-attributes)) attribute to your `<div horizontal layout>` element.

See [here](http://jsbin.com/wufaho/1/edit?html,output).